# Failed to run service inside docker container

Tags: makefile, docker, onedrive, dockerfile, docker-compose

I need to create docker container which is running Onedrive client so I can synchronize the data to my Onedrive account.

This is the project that I've created https://github.com/rischanlab/onedrive-ubuntu-docker

I created a Makefile, by that file we can make command easily.

This is the example of my Makefile

```
shell:
    @echo
    @echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo "Shelling in in production mode"
    @echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @docker-compose -p $(PROJECT_ID) run data /bin/bash

statusd:
    @echo
    @echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo "Knowing Onedrive daemon status"
    @echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @docker-compose -p $(PROJECT_ID) run data onedrive-d status

startd:
    @echo
    @echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo "Running Onedrive daemon"
    @echo "------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @docker-compose -p $(PROJECT_ID) run data onedrive-d start
```

The problem is when I run `make startd` the log said that onedrive-d has been start but I still can't sync my data to my onedrive account, then I checked the status by using command `make statusd` and the log said that onedrive-d is not running. I am so confused why it happend.

Note:

1. When I login to the container `make shell` then I start manualy
   `onedrive-d start`. it works, the daemon can start well and my files
   successfuly synchronized.
2. For the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` can be seen on my
   project that I provide above.

so, is there anyone can explain to me, whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose run` doesn't do what you're expecting here. It's for running one-off tasks in a **new** container, not for `exec`'ing  inside an existing container.

You can use `docker exec -ti <container name>` if you need to get into the same container.